# How to read PPT file using PHPpowerpoint?

Tags: php, powerpoint, phppowerpoint

how to read PPTX files using PHP powerpoint? is there any way to serialize the ppt file like in PHPexcel?

Answer (score 1):

PHPPowerPoint cannot yet read ppt or pptx files.

In theory, the serialized writer in PHPPowerPoint will generate files that can subsequently be read again by PHPPowerPoint, but as it's a serialization of the PHPPowerPoint object, other applications can't use it. It is still necessary to create a PHPPowerPoint object manually in the first place though.

Note that the serialized format has now been dropped from PHPExcel